# If statement inside for loop in R

Tags: r, loops

I'm trying to create an if statement inside a for loop in R.

When mk_precip_mm = NA, decade = 1960, and month = 1, I want that row of the "shifted" column to be rewritten as the abby_precip_mm column + 100.

The dataframe looks like this (simplified):

```
  Date.Time month year decade abby_precip_mm mk_precip_mm  shifted
1    1/1/61     1 1961   1960            1.0           NA       NA
2    1/2/61     1 1961   1960            0.0           NA       NA
3    1/3/61     1 1961   1960            5.3           NA       NA
4    1/4/61     1 1961   1960           18.3           NA       NA
5    1/5/74     1 1974   1970           22.4           3.1      NA
6    1/6/74     1 1974   1970            1.3           2.2      NA
```

This is what I have so far:

```
for(i in 1:nrow(df1)) {  
  mk_precip_mm <- df1[i, "mk_precip_mm"]
  abby_precip_mm <- df1[i, "abby_precip_mm"]
  month <- df1[i, "month"]
  decade <- df1[i, "decade"]
  shifted <- df1[i, "shifted"]
  
    if(is.na(mk_precip_mm)) {
  
      if(month == 1 & decade == 1960) {
        shifted <- df1[i, "abby_precip_mm"] + 100
      }     
  }
}
```

However, the output shows no change in the "shifted" column. Any advice?

Comment: Because you have only changed the variable called `shifted`, not your data.frame. You would need `df1[i, 'shifted'] <- df1[i, "abby_precip_mm"] + 100`, or end with `df1$shifted <- shifted` after the loop. But you don't need that for loop at all. Instead consider an approach like `df1$shifted  <- ifelse(is.na(df1$mk_precip_mm) & df1$month == 1 & df1$decade == 1960, df1$abby_precip_mm + 100, df1$shifted)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

R's biggest strength is that it comfortably handles vector calculations. You can add two columns together, instead of taking them one value at a time.

To quickly set a column "shifted", you can replace your entire coded with a single line:

```
df1$shifted <- ifelse(is.na(df1$mk_precip_mm) &
                          df1$month == 1 &
                          df1$decade == 1960,
                      df1$abby_precip_mm + 100,
                      NA
                      )
```

The dollar sign is an easy way of accessing the values in a column.